# Electron Menu change item Label dynamically

Tags: javascript, electron, contextmenu

I can't find a way of changing a label of a context menu. I want to change the label depending on the type of the node I right click on.

I've tried this without success:

```
$('#region-sortable').bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      liRegionSelectionne = e.target;
      if(liRegionSelectionne.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span"){
        menuEditRegion.items[0].label = "Modifier cette Remarque";
      }else{
        menuEditRegion.items[0].label = "Modifier cette Région";
      }     
        menuEditRegion.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow());
    });
```

I can see in the console that the label is changed in the object `items[0]`, but when the menu pops up the label is the one I put when I originally declared the menu.

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this: (In case anyone needs)

```
const menuTemplate = [{
    label: 'Options',
    submenu: [
       {
         label: 'Menu label',
         click() { //do stuff }
       }
    ]
}];

// Change menu items when user login. Fetching value from renderer process
ipcMain.on('logged-in', (event, args) => {
    if (args !== true) {
        return;
    }

    // Modify menu item status
    menuTemplate[0].submenu[0].label = 'New label';

    // Rebuild menu
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

Comment: IMO, the key point here is recreation of the whole Menu instance and reassigning it. Worked for me when trying to update tray context menu.

Answer (score 3):

After opening an issue on GitHub, the answer is that actually the Menu is not designed to be dynamic, and probably will not be for a long time.

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12633

Comment: I discovered this, so I rebuild the menu every time I need to change text. I'd be interested to know if anybody has a better workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue myself, wanting to change the menu from the renderer process. I created [ipc-flux](https://github.com/harryparkdotio/ipc-flux) to handle this. Its similar to the vuex flux pattern.

From there, create an action in the main process to change a specific menu label to a string provided in the payload.

Then dispatch it from the renderer process

```
$('#region-sortable').bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    liRegionSelectionne = e.target;
    if(liRegionSelectionne.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span"){
        ipcFlux.dispatch('main', 'menuItemsLabelChange', 'Modifier cetter Remarque');
    } else{
        ipcFlux.dispatch('main', 'menuItemsLabelChange', 'Modifier cetter Région');
    }     
    menuEditRegion.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow());
});
```

Comment: I've modified my interface and add a Menu Item and modified the code to enable or disable the option. And even if the cod is still in the renderer it works.